# Смена текста в других Activity

Tags: android, activity, android-intent, textview

Всем доброго времени суток!
Коротко : 
хочу сделать список книг,при нажатии на которую будет открываться одна и та же Activivty но с разным текстом внутри Textview

Не Коротко :
Начал обучаться программированию на андроид,и решил попробовать сделать свою простенькую читалку 
Много раз переделал,и пришёл к выводу,что хочу сделать одну Activivty и использовать её для всех книг,меняя только textView в нём 
Как это можно реализовать?
String array с названиями и вторая с книгами - уже есть 
Прослушиватель list View тоже 
Но постоянно вылетает при открытии Activity 
Не ругайте если что написал не так,впервые что-то подобное пишу

> 2020-01-24 19:46:25.552 5013-5013/com.flametime.will20
>   E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
>
> 2020-01-24 19:46:25.552 5013-5013/com.flametime.will20
>   E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback:
>   handleReceiveCallback
>
> 2020-01-24 19:46:25.575 5013-5013/com.flametime.will20
>   E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke
>   virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference
>           at com.flametime.will20.GeneralStoriesActivity$1.onItemClick(GeneralStoriesActivity.java:53)

дальше все в логах красное,тоже скидывать?

Вот тот кусок

```
LvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
LvMain.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        String selectedItem = stories[position];

        StorieText.setText(selectedItem); //Строчка 53 (StorieText в другой Activity)

        startActivity(Story0); 



    }
});
```

Comment: Покажите лог ошибки. Всё остальное, по большему счёту - неважно

Comment: Скинул в ответы

Comment: Надеюсь, у вас `StorieText` не статическая переменная из другой активити? Если да - то оно так не работает, надо всё это в другой активити делать. И переменные надо с маленькой буквы называть - иначе становится непонятно что должен код делать.

Comment: Мои знания не позволяют мне точно понять все написанное Вами) Если я сделаю для каждого текста - свою страницу,отдельную,это не будет извращением? И можно ли как-то один шаблон использовать,так как там кроме текста ничего нет. В интернете очень мало инфы на эту тему. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Чтобы сделать совсем правильно - надо отказываться от активити, использовать фрагменты, использовать фреймворки для MVP, DI, DB etc. Меж этой крайность и "сделать как-ниубудь, чтоб работало" почти бесконечная череда вариантов. Как вам сделать, чтобы не переписывать всё с нуля - сложно сказать без кода. То, что вы выложили - по идее не должно работать и/или даже компилироваться. И в любом случае этого кода мало. Так-то там всё можно в пару строк сделать, но надо код видеть.

Comment: вам безусловно надо делать все в одной активити, которая будет отображать разный текст. объяснить все одним ответом довольно сложно, так как это целый пласт информации по многим темам. как это все работает, вы можете ознакомиться на примере шаблона MasterDetail Flow (список с заголовками, при нажатии на пункт списка выводится подробная информация по этому пункту), который входит в набор стандартных шаблонов Android Studio. Вообще, если вы хотите чему то научится, то нужно много читать литературу, а не сайты. например книгу "Android. Программирование для профессионалов. 3-е издание" Б.Филлипс